# Kamon, Statsd, Grafana Disk Space

Tags: docker, graphite, grafana, statsd, kamon

I recently setup Kamon, Statsd, Graphite, Grafana to monitor my akka application. I used the Docker container for Statsd, Graphite and Grafana that most tutorials suggest and it all worked fine until recently when I noticed the Grafana dashboard was starting to lag and become unresponsive. 
Its now become unresponsive and the reason is the machine hosting the Docker container has run out of space...

```
85790556    /var/lib/docker
85786096    /var/lib/docker/aufs
42922104    /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff
42863828    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt
42863668    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/1daed028a6ca7041dc95257b27328324936f548d2cfc589d6e3c94ac3d8cc63b
41878192    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/1daed028a6ca7041dc95257b27328324936f548d2cfc589d6e3c94ac3d8cc63b/opt
41793244    /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/1daed028a6ca7041dc95257b27328324936f548d2cfc589d6e3c94ac3d8cc63b
41754416    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/1daed028a6ca7041dc95257b27328324936f548d2cfc589d6e3c94ac3d8cc63b/opt/graphite
```

This is likely from the monitoring stats building up.
So I've two questions...

1. How do I safely clean up space in this container to get it running again.
2. Can I configure statsd or graphite to periodically purge data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to configure carbon to manage the retention of your data. You can define several intervals to keep your data and at which resolution.

For instance in `storage-schemas.conf`:

```
retentions = 15s:7d,1m:21d,15m:5y
```

This retention will mean that the metrics will be kept for 7 days with a resolution of 15 seconds. Then carbon will aggregate the older data with a precision of 1 min and keep them for 21 days. Then keep the data for 5 years with a resolution of 15 min.

Depending on your need and your storage capacity, you can configure several retention policies.

In `storage-aggregation.conf` you can define how carbon should aggregate your metrics when changing the resolution: take the `min`, `max`, `avg`, `sum` ...

More information in [carbon documentation](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-schemas-conf)

Comment: This is a better solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here...

https://github.com/kamon-io/docker-grafana-graphite/issues/16

I needed to attach to the Docker Container and run...

find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats -type f -mtime +3 -delete && find /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats -type d -empty -delete

Comment: What that's doing is removing the whisper files for graphite series that haven't been written to in the last 3 days.

Comment: Is that a good or bad thing?!?! And is there a better solution?